# meaning of 'the other end' here

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is from [a news article](https://www.npr.org/sections/goatsandsoda/2023/05/10/1175303067/a-plastic-sheet-with-a-pouch-could-be-a-game-changer-for-maternal-mortality) :

> It's a startling statistic. Every year, 70,000 women around the world
> basically bleed to death after childbirth. That averages out to nearly
> 200 deaths a day and makes postpartum hemorrhage a leading cause of
> maternal deaths.
>
> Now a new study points to a surprisingly simple and inexpensive
> solution: Basically, if the woman lies on a plastic sheet with a small
> transparent pouch at **the other end** to collect the blood, the
> medical team has an immediate sense of how much danger she's in and
> can take swift action.

I'm curious whether 'the other' in this context refers to the head end or the foot end.

If it refers to the foot end, is it common to use 'the other' to refer to the foot end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means: the end of the sheet opposite to where the woman is lying.

A sentence later in the article may clarify things:

> One end of the drape is placed under a woman who has just delivered vaginally; the other end tapers into the collection pouch that hangs down from her bed.

Comment: Thank you very much.